# Meaning of *((uint32_t*)&..) in C

Tags: c, keil, uint32-t

```
LPC_CAN1->TDA1 = *(uint32_t *) &msg->data[0];    // Write first 4 data bytes
```

please tell me why this *(uint32_t *) is used and what is the purpose of this "*" before and after the uint32_t

Answer (score 5):

Objective of this code is to copy first 4 bytes present at `msg->data[0]` to `LPC_CAN1->TDA1`.

`&msg->data[0]` gives the address of msg->data[0].

`(uint32_t *) &msg->data[0]` casts that address to be an address pointing to a 32-bit unsigned integer.

`*(uint32_t *) &msg->data[0]` reads uint32_t value (4-byte unsigned integer) from the address.

Hope that makes sense.